# How to check if instance exists if variable not existing?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I have a button which imports a module with a class.
The class (varClass) creates a window.

If i click the button once again, i try this:

```
if var:
    var.toggleUI()
else :
    var = varClass()
```

But var doesn' exist the first time you create the window after opening Maya. How can i get this working?

Comment: You mean you get a `NameError` exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could catch the `NameError` exception:

```
try:
    var.toggleUI()
except NameError:
    var = varClass()
```

If you needed call `toggleUI` the first time too, just try the name itself:

```
try:
    var
except NameError:
    var = varClass()

var.toggleUI()
```

I'm not familiar with Maja, but if you can define the name elsewhere first and simply set it to `None` there, then your code would work too, if not better.

Comment: Setting to None, as MrGumble said before, wouldn't work. It should be executed outside  my button, in a init file. That would be good for nearly 40 tools i'm working on. 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant for you to set it to `None` outside of the handler. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use Exceptions:

```
try:
    var.toggleUI()
except NameError:
    var = varClass()
    var.toggleUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this inside a button, you should offload the management of the `var` to the the module you're importing.  Let the module handle the instantiation and the button lets the module do the heavy lifting.  Rendundant imports dont hurt as long as the import has no side-effects (which  it should not have if you're doing it right).

The module does something like this:

```
class SampleGui(object):
     # all sorts of good stuff here

_sample_gui_instance = None
def get_instance():
    _sample_gui_instance = sample_gui_instance or SampleGui()
    return _sample_gui_instance
```

and the button just does

```
import SampleGuiModule
SampleGuiModule.get_instance().toggleUI()
```

This is the same check as the ones in everybody else's answer, but I think by delegating instance management to the module, instead of the button, you can have any level of complexity or initialization going on and share it between buttons, hotkeys or other scripts transparently.

I saved a few characters by using the `or` instead of `if... is None`; this will be tricky of for some reason a `SampleGui` truth tests as false.  But it will only do that if you make force it to.

possibly useful: [maya callbacks cheat sheet](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet#.WPqom4Qs5xU.link)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dir function

```
a=5
'a' in dir()
'b' in dir()
```

This will print

```
True
False
```

So in your case

```
if 'var' in dir():
    var.toggleUI()
else :
    var = varClass()
```

Answer (score -3):

Default your `var`, and use it as a test:

```
var = None
if var is None:
  var = varClass()
var.toggleUI()
```

Comment: I think your answer is not useful. I cannot make var = None, i'm executing a script inside a button. If i do that, the variable will always be set to None.

Comment: Set ``var = None`` in the script containing the button, not within the scope of the button. This way, the ``varClass`` instance is kept throughout the scope of the calling script.