# How to catch - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'

Tags: python

I Know what the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'
```

means, but what I cannot figure out is how to catch it.  Basically i want to check to see if my object is created or not.

I want to do something like this:

```
try:
    test = self.myObject.values()
except:
    print "Error happened"
```

But every time I do I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Can someone tell me how to catch this?

Comment: Where do you assign `self.myObject`? It's being assigned to `None`. You should catch it by doing `if self.myObject is None: handle_case()`. Alternatively wrap it in `try: test = self.myObject.values(); except AttributeError as e: handle_case()`

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624679/how-to-check-if-instance-exists-if-variable-not-existing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the hasattr(object, name) method which returns True or False. If you try to access an attribute which does not exist you will always receive an exception. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr

If you still wish to catch the exception then simply do a try/catch block with exception type 'AttributeError'

Comment: "AttributeError" didnt help. The "TypeError" worked

Comment: @viru What Python version did you test?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to do this. If you just want to see if an object exists, you can do:

```
if self.myObject:
    # do stuff with my object
else:
    # do other stuff

#Or the more explicit form, if myObject could be 'falsey' normally, like an empty list/dict
if self.myObject is not None:
```

If you can assign a reasonable default, you can one-line this like so

```
test = self.myObject.something if self.myObject else default_value
```

Where `default_value` is whatever you can use as a reasonable default. Thanks to python's [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), this is safe, as the `self.myObject.something` will never be evaluated if `self.myObject` is `None` (or falsey).